# Enable workspace resolution by default for m2e launch configurations

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, m2e

When I use `Run as > Maven Build` in Eclipse, "Resolve Workspace Artifacts" checkbox is unchecked by default. Is it possible to make it checked by default?

Answer (score 1):

Number of Maven plugins may conflict with "Resolve Workspace Artifacts" feature (e.g. maven war plugin), so it is generally not recommended.

However, if you really need that feature, "Run as / Maven build" remembers previously launched and saved configurations and you can invoke them again from the same menu or using keyboard shortcut Alt-Shift-X, M.